# Probability of incorrectly spelling a word

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm currently trying to teach myself Statistics and have an exam question that I need a bit of help on:

```
 Suppose that 60% of a large population know how to spell the word 'accommodation'. 
 Five people were selected at random from the population and asked to spell the word

 1- What is the probability that exactly 2 of the 5 spelled the word correctly?
 2- What is the probability that at least one person spelled the word correctly?
 3- Given that the first person spelled the word correctly, what is the probability that 
 exactly 4 of the 5 spelled it correctly?
```

Please bare in mind that I'm new to statistics so a simple explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out the Binomial Distribution

Comment: Not crazy about the phrasing.  Are we to assume that everyone who knows how to spell the word always spells it correctly and that anyone who does not know how to spell it never spells it correctly?  Neither of these seem like very good assumptions to me (I know how to spell it, but I expect I get it wrong a third of the time...and even if you don't know how to spell it I figure you have a pretty good chance of guessing correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose that 60% of a large population know how to spell the word 'accommodation'.

The phrasing of this problem is poorly worded.   Let us instead suppose that $60\%$ of the large population will spell the word correctly when asked.

As the population is *large*, then we may approximate that the probabilities of this happening for members of a small (and hopefully representative) sample are mutually independent.

> Five people were selected at random from the population and asked to spell the word.

Under that approximation, the count of members in the sample who will spell the word correctly shall have a **Binomial Distribution**.   Let us call the count $X$, then we write: $$X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(5, 0.60)\\ \mathsf P(X{=}k)~=~\binom{5}{k}\frac{6^k4^{5-k}}{10^5}~\mathbf 1_{k\in\{0,..,6\}}$$

> 1- What is the probability that exactly 2 of the 5 spelled the word correctly?

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=2)~=&~\binom{5}{2}\frac{6^24^3}{10^5} \\=&~ 0.2304\end{align}$$

> 2- What is the probability that at least one person spelled the word correctly?

It is the probability that not all of them spelled the word incorrectly.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\geq 1)~=&~1-\mathsf P(X=0)\\=&~ \ldots\end{align}$$

> 3- Given that the first person spelled the word correctly, what is the probability that exactly 4 of the 5 spelled it correctly?

Let $X_n$ be the indicator that the $n$-th person asked spelled the word correctly.   ($X_n=1$ is the event that they did, $X_n=0$ is the event that they did not.)

Then $X=\sum_{n=1}^5 X_n$.

Under our assumption of independence, the count of those who spell the word correctly among the *remaining* 4 people is also Binomially distributed.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=2}^5 X_n \sim&~ \mathcal {Bin}(4, 0.60)
\\[1ex] \mathsf P(X=4\mid X_1=1) ~=&~ \mathsf P\left(\sum_{n=2}^5 X_n=3\right) \\=&~ \ldots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

> What is the probability that exactly $2$ of the $5$ spelled the word correctly?

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{2}\binom5n\cdot\left(\frac{60}{100}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{60}{100}\right)^{5-n}$$

> What is the probability that at least one person spelled the word correctly?

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{5}\binom5n\cdot\left(\frac{60}{100}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{60}{100}\right)^{5-n}$$

Comment: thanks for your reply @barakmanos is this a formula or something I should just know?

Comment: @LaurenBurke: Yes, as mentioned in the first comment to your question.

Comment: @LaurenBurke: Second thought, I wouldn't call it "just know", I think that you should also try to understand.

Comment: Sorry that was bad phrasing. By 'just know' I meant is it general knowledge when doing statistics and something I should have been able to spot. For the third part what I'm thinking is: $$\sum\limits_{n=4}^{4}\binom4n\cdot\left(\frac{60}{100}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{60}{100}\right)^{4-n}$$

Comment: @LaurenBurke: I'd change that $\sum\limits_{n=4}^{4}$ to $\sum\limits_{n=3}^{3}$.

Comment: can I ask why 3?

Comment: Never mind I can see now Thank you for all your help!